# entering null values through a windows form and inserting value into a databse

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, database

I have a form that inserts entered values into a database.  The data type of the entered values is float.  I am trying to figure out how to accept a null value into the field, then insert that into a SQL Server database using C# as null.

The form runs exactly as I want it to until I run it without entering anything into the form.  When I try to convert the form value (as Text) to float I get an unhandled exception dialog.  I used the code as follows:

```
float? decNum = Convert.ToSingle(txtDecimalNum.Text);
```

I think it is failing because I am trying to convert a null value to a float (please let me know if that is not correct).  If that is the case, then I am stumped as to how to handle this.

The code behind is in c#, and the database is SQL Server 2014.

Thank you in advance for any assistance you can provide.

Here is the complete code block as requested by sstan.  Thank you!

```
         private void btnEnter_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            float? decNum = string.IsNullOrEmpty(txtDecimalNum.Text)
                ? (float?)null : Convert.ToSingle(txtDecimalNum.Text);

            string connection = null;
            connection = "Data Source=homeoffice\\sqlexpress;Initial Catalog=testApp;Integrated Security=True";
            SqlConnection conn;
            conn = new SqlConnection(connection);

            string sqlQuery;
            sqlQuery = "Insert into testTable(decNum1) values(@decNum)";

            conn.Open();
            SqlCommand cmdIns = new SqlCommand(sqlQuery, conn);

            cmdIns.Parameters.AddWithValue("@decNum", SqlDbType.Float).Value = decNum;
            cmdIns.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

Comment: Quick question. What is the number you're trying to convert actually *for*? Most of the time you'd be better off using decimal - it's got a smaller (albeit still large) range, but unlike float is actually precise. Store prices (for example) as floats and you'll start finding the values drifting as you perform more operations on them.

Comment: @eftpotrm, I originally had it as decimal but in the course of trying different things I changed it to float.  I am changing it back as you suggest.  Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll want to look into the `TryParse` series of functions.  For instance:

```
float decNum;

if (!float.TryParse(txtDecimalNum.Text, out decNum))
{
    //The value in the box isn't a float.  Enter a null value
}
else
{
    //You now have access to the float value 'decNum'
}
```

The benefit of this is that if the form is submitted with something other than a valid float, the TryParse will handle the error checking for you.

Comment: Thank you Trent Sartain!  This exactly was what I was looking for.  I have added it to my prod application and it works like a charm.

Answer (score 1):

You can always check to see if the field is empty before trying to convert it:

```
float? decNum = string.IsNullOrEmpty(txtDecimalNum.Text) 
                    ? (float?)null
                    : Convert.ToSingle(txtDecimalNum.Text);
```

Comment: Thanks sstan.  I have had that in my code along the way, but still need to insert the null value into the database.  When I run the entire app I get an unhandled exception with the following: 'Additional information: The parameterized query '(@decNum nvarchar(4000))Insert into testTable(decNum1) values(@d' expects the parameter '@decNum', which was not supplied.'  I am stumped on where I go from here.

Comment: That sounds like a different question altogether, and you haven't provided the relevant code to diagnose that specific problem.  Consider editing your post to show how you are persisting the information to the database.  In fact, by the error message, I have a feeling that this has nothing to do with a null value.  But show the code to be sure.

Comment: sstan, I edited the original question to include the code block of the button click event.  Thanks!

Comment: I marked the question as a duplicate.  You'll find your answer in that other thread.

Comment: Thank you sstan!  That worked perfectly.

Comment: @Jerry: If that other thread helped fix your problem, then make sure to mark your question as a duplicate.  That way, others will know where to look for the answer.

Comment: @ssan, thank you for the suggestion. I have marked it and hope it helps someone else.

Answer (score 0):

What happens if you log the value of txtDecimalNum.Text?

You can probably save yourself some time in debugging and switch to this version:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.single.tryparse(v=vs.110).aspx

But, you'll probably still need to track down why your data is coming back in an unexpected form.